# How to delete files from Amazon Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I've been using Amazon S3 and glacier for a while to backup some servers. The bill has been steadily growing and decided to do a bit of spring cleaning.

From the S3 browser I could see all the archived files so selected and deleted the bulk of them and thought I was done but I just got my latest invoice and the amount of Glacier storage has not decreased.

How do I delete these old backups. Is there an easy to use tool?

Comment: "Is there a tool?" is an off-topic question, but "did I miss something" is probably what you should investigate...such as the surcharge for deleting glacier objects less than 90 days old, which could have temporarily caused your charges to be higher than expected...

Comment: I wasn't just looking at the cost, but the storage they were billing for. It went from 1.5TB to 1.6TB. This was after I deleted the glacier items out of the S3 bucket. Is there a lag perhaps?

Comment: They bill for total storage hours over the course of the month that ended, so there shouldn't be significant lag.  Have you activated detailed billing?